# I want to display an alert for every 10th time the application gets open in swift

Tags: ios, swift2

Good afternoon did not find a specific answer, I decided to ask him myself
I need to display an alert, every 10th time the application is opened.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean, it's not clear at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you mean you want to show alert every 10th time the app opened, you can do it like this:
In your AppDelegate, Save the count Int in UserDefaults and increment it each time the app opens. then check for the number when it's multiple of 10's.

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
      ...
    func showAlert(count:Int) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "You have open the app \(count) times", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        // show the alert
        window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var  count = defaults.integerForKey("count") ?? 0
    count += 1
    defaults.setInteger(count, forKey: "count")
    if count % 10 == 0 {  // each 10th time the app opens
        showAlert(count)
    }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep a count of the number of times the app has launched in the `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` using `NSUserDefaults` and on the 10th multiple show the alert.